# Group javascript xml output by letters or other attributes

Tags: javascript, xml, grouping

I have an xml document that looks something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mapPoints>
<annotation cat="A" title="123" type="pointer"/>
<annotation cat="A" title="333" type="pointer"/>
<annotation cat="B" title="555" type="pointer"/>
</mapPoints>
```

I am parsing the XML into my javascript document. 
Now, I want to group the output of my xml file in different divs base on the cat in the xml so that the markup would look something like this

```
<div class="A">
<ul>
<li>123 cat A</li>
<li>333 cat A</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="B">
<ul>
<li>555 cat B</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My parsing is working properly but I don't know how I would group the entries and then output them into different divs. The solution needs to be dynamic since it could be a lot of categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery and assuming you have your xml in a variable `xml`, try this:

```
$(xml).find('mapPoints annotation').each(function() {
    var class = $(this).attr('cat');
    if ($('div.' + class).length == 0) {
        $('#annotations').append('<div class="' + class + '"><ul></ul></div>');
    }
    $('div.' + class + ' ul').append(getLiFromXml(this));
});
```

`getLiFromXml` is a function that returns `<li>123 cat A</li>` for `<annotation cat="A" title="123" type="pointer"/>` - hopefully, you can easily write it.

**UPDATE**

Updated the code to add a `div` first. I assumed that you store all your `div`s in a container (`div`, `td`, whatever...) with `id="annotations"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Wouldn't that give me a div for every cat A I have so if i have 10 entrys with cat A all of them would create a new cat A div?

Comment: I assume `$('div.' + class + ' ul')` to be pre-created. I'll edit the post to say that.